# Resolving page numbers from PyPDF2 getOutlines()

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF 2 to process some PDF files. I'm hoping to extract outline/ToC data from files that have it, essentially to try to get a sense of which section of the document a given page corresponds to.

[According to the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader.getOutlines), `PdfFileReader`'s `getOutlines` method should return a nested list of `Destination` objects. Then, [according to the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/Destination.html#PyPDF2.generic.Destination), each of these should have a `page` (int) attribute.

Unfortunately, this isn't the case with the files I've tried. Instead, I get `indirectObject`s, which resolve to `PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject`s. I can't figure out how to get the `Destination` objects I'm expecting, or how to extract meaningful page numbers from the `indirectObject`s I'm getting instead.

The ultimate goal is to, given an outline's page number, be able to pass that page number to `getPage()` and then call `extractText()`.

Any guidance much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`pypdf.PdfReader` has a [`get_destination_page_number`](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#pypdf.PdfReader.get_destination_page_number) method that gives you the page number from a `Destination` object.

You might also want to try [`pikepdf`](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf/), they also have [outline support](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/outlines.html).

Comment: "PyPDF2 is not really updated anymore": It is :-) I'm the new maintainer since April 

Comment: Good to know! Thanks and godspeed.