# Page number of added bookmarks with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I have added pdf files using `PdfFileMerger` from `PyPDF2` and added a bookmark at the beginning of each pdf file using `PdfFileMerger.addbookmark`. When I open the new file with `PdfFileReader` and extract the pages, where the bookmarks wer placed, I get for the page number `-1`.

I use the following code for merging:

```
merger = PdfFileMerger
for path in paths:
    merger.append(path, import_bookmarks=False)
    merger.addBookmark(f"{title}", page)
merger.write(save_path)
merger.close()
```

For reading the file I use:

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(file, "rb")
for i in pdf.getOutlines():
    pdf.getDestinationPageNumber(i)
```

Why is the page number `-1` for the new bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the -1 value because the method `getDestinationPageNumber` is not finding the page associated with the Destination object, see the [documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.outline). In addition, outline iteration might be broken in PyPDF2, as suggested by this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447660/5661001). You can achieve what you want with this code:

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(file, "rb")
for i in pdf.outline:
    print(i.page)
```

Comment: You need to replace pdf.getOutlines() by pdf.outline now

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `getOutlines()` is indeed deprecated. Also updated the documentation link.